# Zoom won't update (or allow login)

Tags: zoom-meeting

I'm using [Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)](https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/), 64-bit, Gnome version 3.36.8 (it's updated).

Zoom (5.7.4) will not allow me to login until I update (5.13.10).  But when I update this is what I get:

> sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
>
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Note, selecting 'zoom' instead of './zoom_amd64.deb' Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies: zoom : **Depends: [libxcb-cursor0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libxcb-cursor-dev) but it is not installable** **Depends: [libegl1-mesa](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libegl1-mesa-dev) but it is not installable**  E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Any suggestions?

Note: I did submit a support ticket with zoom directly too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the files that Zoom wanted were only in the Ubuntu repo "universe" which I did not have enabled (I never disabled that repo so it must not be enabled by default for some reason).

Here is what I did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
```

The missing dependencies (libxcb-cursor0 and libegl1-mesa) were then able to install and all went well (as it has for the last 3+ years of updates before this).

Note: the Zoom support desk was completely useless.  They absolutely were a waste of time.

Comment: Packages from 'universe' are *community supported* and have three years (maximum) only of guaranteed supported life for LTS releases (*9 months for some too*), thus are NOT *enabled* on Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server.. installs which include only packages with five years of *guaranteed* support for LTS releases. Manual *enabling* is required so its you introducing the shorter supported life packages to your system; a step some users are unwilling to do. Don't forget 3 years is up for 20.04 ('universe' or community packages) end of next month (April 2023).

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu